# When should I add orange peels to my homebrew?

Tags: yeast, techniques, ingredients, fruit

I've been planning to experiment with orange peels for a while now, but I don't know when to add them, when should I throw them in?

Last 15 minutes with the aroma hops? At flame-out? After primary? I have no idea really.

I read somewhere that citric acid and other compounds in oranges can be harmful for the yeast or inhibit their activity. Should I use fresh peels or dried ones, what are the chemical nuances to orange use in homebrew?

Thanks in advance for any advice or pointer, links and articles are very welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It really depends on what you're after.  Traditionally, dried bitter orange peel is added late in the boil for bitterness.  Dried or fresh sweet orange peel can be added late in the boil for a bit of flavor, and fresh sweet orange peel can be added to the secondary for aroma.  So, you need to think about and define what it is you want the orange peel to do in order to decide when and how to use it and what type to use.  BTW, there is not enough citric acid in orange peels to worry about the pH change.